# If $U(r,\theta)$ is harmonic, then $U(1/r,\theta)$ is also harmonic.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

So I know we have to proceed by the chain rule and just wanted to verify the first step to see if I'm on the right track:

Let $V(x,t):=U(m,n)$ where $m=1/r$ and $n=\theta$. Then, by construction of $U$: $$U_{mm}+mU_m+m^2U_{nn}=0.$$

This is the correct first step right? I can proceed from here easily if this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation isn't true, as you have $U_{mm} + \frac 1m U_m  + \frac{1}{m^2}U_{\theta\theta} = 0$. To notice this just replace $r=m$ in the general equation for harmonic equations in polar coordinates.

Anyway it would be better if you directly prove that $V(r, \theta) = U\left(m=\frac 1r, \theta\right)$ satisfues the relation. Compute $V_{r}, V_{rr}$ and $V_{\theta\theta}$. You will get:

$$V_r = U_m \cdot \left(-\frac 1{r^2} \right)$$
$$V_{rr} = U_{mm} \left(\frac 1{r^4} \right) + U_m \left(\frac 2{r^3} \right)$$
$$V_{\theta\theta} = U_{\theta\theta}$$

Now we have:

$$V_{rr} + \frac 1r V_r + \frac{1}{r^2}V_{\theta\theta} = U_{mm} \left(\frac 1{r^4} \right) + U_m \left(\frac 2{r^3} \right) + U_m \cdot \left(-\frac 1{r^3} \right) + \left(\frac 1{r^2} \right)U_{\theta\theta} = \frac{1}{r^4} \left(U_{mm} + rU_m  + r^2U_{\theta\theta} \right) = \frac{1}{r^4} \left(U_{mm} + \frac 1m U_m  + \frac{1}{m^2}U_{\theta\theta} \right) = \frac{1}{r^4} \cdot 0 = 0$$

Hence $U\left(m=\frac 1r, \theta\right) = V(r, \theta) $ is harmonic

Comment: Ah, thank you for the clarification and also the answer, will be nice to compare it once I've had a go with the correct first step that you've given me.

Comment: For $V_{rr}$, should it not be $$U_{mm}\Big(\frac{1}{r^4}\Big)+U_{m\theta}\Big(\frac{2}{r^3}\Big)?$$

Comment: @thesmallprint Using the product and chain rule we have: 

$$V_{rr} = (U_{m})_r \left(- \frac 1{r^2} \right) + U_m \left(\frac 2{r^3} \right) =  (U_{mm} \cdot m_r + U_{m\theta} \cdot \theta_r) \left(- \frac 1{r^2} \right)+ U_m \left(\frac 2{r^3} \right)  $$

Now note that $\theta_r =0$, as $\theta$ doesn't depend on $r$. You shold be able to get what I got

Comment: Ah yes, I've got it now. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If $U$ is harmonic in some open disk centered at the origin (or in all of the plane,) then so are the real and imaginary parts of $U$. So, without loss of generality, assume that $U$ is real. Then $U(r,\theta)=\Re u(e^{i\theta})$ where $u(z)$ is a power series. Then $u(\overline{z})$ is harmonic, as is $u(1/\overline{z})$, which has the polar representation $U(1/r,\theta)$.